# Bootstrap navbar goes off-page in wordpress after including width:100%

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Bootstrap navbar goes off-page in wordpress after including width:100% on .container div.
Header and footer are already full-width.

I have page template wrapped in a container which I need in full width.

Now when I add

```
.container{
  width:100% !important;
}
```

or

```
<div class="container" style="width:100% !important">
```

the template page becomes full width but the navbar spans a little off-page as well. (NOTE: none of the navbar elements or classes are wrapped with a container class).
Tried many things but nothing seems to work.
here's a snapshot 
[navbar spans off-page to the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHaTC.png)

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '')); ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</nav>

 <div class="container-fluid">
 <section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row no-gutter">
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                    <img src="http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/tynillle/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                        <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                            <div class="project-category text-faded">
                                Category
                            </div>
                            <div class="project-name">
                                Project Name
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </div>            

        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

Comment: Describe clearly....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the container-fluid class instead of changing the .container styling..

```
<div class="container-fluid"> Your content... </div>
```

instead of

```
<div class="container"> Your content... </div>
```

Did that help?

**UPDATE**

If for some reason you still want to edit the styling of container class then you should add this styling to your css:

```
.container {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          left: 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

This your html:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    </div>
    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <?php wp_list_pages(array('title_li' => '')); ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-inner -->
</nav>

<section class="no-padding" id="portfolio">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">
            <a href="#" class="portfolio-box">
                <img src="http://i341.photobucket.com/albums/o377/tynillle/lights.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="">
                <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
                    <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                        <div class="project-category text-faded">
                            Category
                       </div>
                         <div class="project-name">
                            Project Name
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>            

    </div>
</div>
```

And this is you css:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Still the same result. :/

Comment: Updated the post with code above. I've changed container to container-fluid and {padding: 0 !important; } is doing the same thing now.

Comment: I tried your code and it works! no problem with the navbar. Can you use bootply to post your full code so I could help you.

Comment: I will update now my answer and post your code as it should be...
Both html and css

Comment: Bootply doesn't show preview could be because of wp php tags? Thank you for the effort. This issue is taking me all day to figure out. Help much appreciated.

Comment: I posted the correct code, both html and css. I tested it and it works! If that is what you were looking for please accept this answer as correct!

Comment: margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
those two worked fine, (I erased the rest of the css, it messed up my layout) but which css elements' parameters' did you override by these? 
Thank you anyway I thought there was some default wordpress padding or something I had to override but couldn't find the exact source. That solved the problem.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you! 
Have a nice day. Greetings from beautiful Thessaloniki, Greece!